# Count only "specific words" visible cells in a filtered pivot table

Tags: excel

I want to count only visible cells in Column Q that say "ME". I tried =COUNTIF(Q1:Q469,"ME") but it gave me the total for ALL of the cells in the table including the unfiltered results. I just want to count how many "ME" that are in Feb. I also tried SUBTOTAL but wasn't able to make it work.
I'm working on an older version of excel.
 [image]

Comment: `SUBTOTAL` and `AGGREGATE` can ignore hidden rows

Comment: How about `=COUNTIFS(K:K,"FEB",Q:Q,"ME")` so you don't need to hide what you don't want counted?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column to your data set with the following formula:

```
=countif(Q1,"ME")
```

This column should return 1s and 0s based on the values in your Inspected by column.

Update the pivot table to include this new data source and hit refresh.

Drag the new column to the value section of your pivot table fields list and summarize by Sum.

Include a grand total row ("on for columns only") in Design. The grand total will give you a total count of "ME" and update accurately as you filter through data.